# How to manipulate images in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I need to implement a class (inherited from sf::Image) that allows me to find 'distance' between two images. By that I mean a measure of how the images differ from each other pixel by pixel (the specifics don't matter). The main idea is to take an image, draw something on it and look at how much it changed. To draw something I need to convert my image into an sf::RenderTexture (probably?). The problem is that I can't draw on sf::RenderTexture inside of a class (only in the main loop directly), it just shows me an empty dark blue background for some reason. How can I fix that?

Comment: If it works "in the main loop directly" it should work "inside of a class", assuming your OpenGL context has been set up by the main function.

Comment: @Botje well, it should but it doesn't, that's why I'm asking the question

Comment: So show us some code (preferably a [mcve]) that exhibits the problem. My random guess i that you are letting some SFML resource fall out of scope while it is still being referenced somewhere.

Comment: Giving some more specifics may help sometome to answer your question. Are you sure you need to convert to `sf::RenderTexture` to draw on it? `sf::Image` instances appear to be drawable [according to the docs](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php), albeit pixel-by-pixel. A minimal code example of your issue will be helpful for us to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't derive from `sf::Image` (see also [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

To go from a `sf::RenderTexture` to an `sf::Image` you can use `renderTexture.getTexture().copyToImage()`, but keep in mind that requires transferring of data from the GPU's VRAM to the CPU's RAM and as such it can be rather slow, meaning you may not want to do that every frame, but only when you need it.

To then compare images, you can access the pixel information with `getPixelsPtr()` on the `sf::Image` instance.

Don't hesitate to check out the official documentation on how to use [`sf::Image`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/latest/classsf_1_1Image.php#details) or [`sf::RenderTexture`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/latest/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php#details).

Comment: thank you, I'm returning to this little project now